# Out of a $5$ card hand, what is the probability of drawing at least $2$ black suits?

Tags: probability, combinations

Drawing $5$ cards from a deck of $52$ cards, what is the probability that **at least** $2$ of them are black suits (clubs or spades)?

More context:
I know that 52 choose 5 would give the 2598960 different possible 5 card hands. I don't know how to make it more specific... I don't know how to adjust for the "at least 2" part of the problem. I think if it were at least 1 is black, would it be something like: probability = 1 - (26/52)(25/52)(24/52)(23/52)(22/52) = 0.979 But I'm not sure how to account for at least two.

This question **is** on topic because it is a similar question to a review question for my Computational Structures exam.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  What have you tried. Where are you stuck? If you show that, you might get a better response.

Answer (score 0):

Some hint. Answer the following questions:

Given a set of integer numbers from 1 to 52:

1. How many subsets of 5 numbers in total.
2. How many subsets of even 5 numbers.
3. How many subsets of even 4 numbers.
4. What is the relationship between the initial problem and questions 1-3 above?
5. How to solve the initial problem answering questions 1-4 above?

Comment: I think a better hint would be to ask in how many ways can exactly two black cards be selected? exactly three black cards be selected? exactly four black cards be selected? exactly five black cards be selected?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your phrasing here. Are you asking for the number of possibilities of 52 choose 5, and then 52 choose 5 that must be even? I think that would be 2598960  and 2598960/2. I see how that might relate to my question in that half the cards are black just like half the numbers must be even... but that doesn't answer my question about how to handle the at least 2. I added more context to my question, my apologies for not being more specific to begin with. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @JoshuaAbbott my idea is to get number of possibilities when all cards are red and number of possibilities when all but one are red. The rest of possibilities will be for "at least two black" which is the number you need. But actually you may consider another approach, see N. F. Taussig comment above for example